# Until or even down to the Tenth Generation

Tags: king-david, ki-teitzei, mamzer

In Deuteronomy 23:3, Moses says that a child of illegitimate birth cannot be accepted into the congregation of the Lord, even to the tenth generation. Safely speaking, does this mean that, even if David is of the tenth generation from Perez, he cannot be accepted in the congregation? Also, what about the fact that Eleazar is a sixth-generation descendant from Perez but yet still became a priest. Is there any solution behind this? Thank you. I gathered this information from this article. http://www.theskepticalreview.com/tsrmag/2bast94.html

Comment: What does Perez have to do with anything?

Comment: Hello Herbert, welcome to Mi Yodeya! ....you reference [Deut. 23:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9987#v=2); did you mean [Deut. 23:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9987#v=3)? Also, what problem do you have with Perez?

Comment: @Shokhet http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Deuteronomy&chapter=23&verse=

Comment: Herbert, your question is latent with Christian assumptions. Are you looking for a Jewish- or Christian-based answer to this?

Comment: Herbert the only famous person that was illegitimate was Jesus because his father Joseph was away, yet his mother still managed to conceive and give birth obviously through some other man who was not her husband. Yehuda married Tamar and was permitted to Because before the giving of the torah after a womans husband died she was allowed to marry her father in law.

Answer (score 4):

Since the term "mamzer" is not what the current English term "bastard" is used for, I will use the correct legal term. One should be aware that in many places the term "mamzer" is translated as "bastard", but should be careful to understand that the meaning is the technical and legal term used in the Torah and not the English connotation (which can include the child of two unmarried people).

Point one is that Peretz was *not* a mamzer. This was acknowledged at the time he was born when Yehudah acknowledged that Tamar had not engaged in forbidden relations with him ("She is more righteous than me"). Therefore, none of his descendants were mamzerim and Elazar's mother did not forbid him from becoming a kohen. At the time, the halachah that became Yibum was in effect for other relatives as well. Thus, Yehudah was allowed to father the child.

As an example see [Yehuda and Tamar – A Story Within a Story?](http://www.vbm-torah.org/parsha.63/09vayeshev.htm)

[Yehuda and Tamar](http://www.breslev.co.il/articles/torah_portion/rabbi_winstons_window/yehuda_and_tamar.aspx?id=17573&language=english)

> Three things were made known by Holy Spirit (Ruach Hakodesh): [once]
>   in the Bais Din of Shem, [once] in the Bais Din of Shmuel HaRamsi, and
>   [once] in the Bais Din of Shlomo. [We learn about] the Bais Din of
>   Shem, as it says, "Yehudah recognized [them] and said, 'She has been
>   more righteous than me ...'." (Bereishis 38:25-26). How did he know
>   [that the child was from him]? Maybe, just as he had been with her,
>   perhaps another had also been with her? Thus, a voice [from Heaven]
>   proclaimed, "From Me (G-d) are the hidden things!" (Makkos 23b)   That
>   is, the whole fiasco and near catastrophe originated with G-d.
>   Elsewhere, the Midrash says that Yehudah wasn't even going in Tamar's
>   direction, but that an angel came along and "steered" Yehudah towards
>   her. That doesn't mean that Yehudah is blameless in the whole affair;
>   quite the contrary (as we have discussed in previous years), it was
>   his own approach to life that set him up for this source of great
>   embarrassment.

If you meant the fact that Rus was a Moabite, only the males were forbidden and not the females. As a result, Dovid HaMelech was also not forbidden, but was a regular member of the tribe of Yehudah.

The daf Yomi in Yevamos actually discusses what the "tenth generation" means in this respect (that is forever) regarding a mamzer as well ([Yebamoth 78b](http://www.halakhah.com/yebamoth/yebamoth_78.html)) Follow the link to see the footnotes.

> Resh Lakish said: A woman mamzer is eligible<sup>25</sup>  after ten
>   generations. This is derived from an analogy between tenth,<sup>26</sup>  and
>   tenth27  mentioned in respect of the Ammonite and the Moabite; as in
>   the latter case the females are permitted<sup>27</sup>  so are they permitted in
>   the former case.<sup>28</sup>  Should you suggest that as in the latter case
>   eligibility begins forthwith so it does in the former case, [it may be
>   replied] that the analogy can only be effective in respect of the
>   generations after the tenth.<sup>29</sup>  But, surely, we learned, MAMZERIM AND
>   NETHINIM ARE INELIGIBLE, AND THEIR INELIGIBILITY IS FOR ALL TIME,
>   WHETHER THEY BE MALES OR FEMALES!<sup>30</sup>  — This is no difficulty: One
>   statement<sup>31</sup>  is in agreement with him who holds<sup>32</sup>  that a deduction is
>   carried through in all respects,<sup>33</sup>  while the other<sup>34</sup>  is in agreement
>   with him who maintains<sup>32</sup>  that a deduction is restricted by its
>   original basis.<sup>35</sup>

Comment: [Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9987) translates the word as "bastard;" just saying.

Comment: @Shokhet While it is the usual translation, there is no word in English that actually means "mamzer". A bastard is the child of two people who are not married. A "mamzer" (depending on particualr psak) is the child of peopele who are forbidden to marry. Examples are the child of a married woman and a man not her husband or a child of "arayos" (such as incest). The problem is that people use the term "bastard" to include two unmarried parents.

Comment: Right; I was just making the point that you can't necessarily be מדייק the word "bastard," by itself -- you need to point out that "*mamzer*" has a special definition. ( *usually only חייבי כריתות, but possibly also חייבי לאוין, according to....R Meir?* )

Comment: @Shokhet I would trust Chabad to understand the difference, however, I would not trust the site quoted to understand the difference based on other postings there.

Comment: @sabbahillel Your diyuk in "bastard" is beyond inane. You are just making everything more confusing by picking a semantic battle unnecessarily. Bastard means a child born of certain inappropriate relationships who is therefore defective in status in some way, even if R Akiva, R Yehoshua and Christians argue about which relationships are included.

Comment: @DoubleAA The point I am making is that the people attempt to use the isur in the Torah to apply to cases that the Torah does not apply it to. Thus someone who wrongly uses the term "bastard" in a place where the Torah uses "mamzer", should not try to claim that the isur of the Torah applies. However, I will remove that sentence (and try to make the point clear)  since it is not directly connected to the question.